# How can I cat the superclass of a class as a type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typing

Lets assume I have two classes A and B like this:

```
class A {}
class B extends A {}
```

Can there be a type `Superclass` (or whatever named) so `Superclass<B> == A`?

Would something like `type Superclass<C> = C extends P ? P : never;` work?

Comment: TypeScript has a [structural](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-structural-typing) type system, not a nominal one.  So for that example, both `A` and `B` are the same type and equivalent to `{}`, the empty interface.  Even if you made them distinct, the structural type system means there is no single "superclass" even when you extend a class, since `class A {foo = "foo"} class B extends A {bar = "bar"}`, `B` is equivalent to `{foo: string, bar: string}` and thus `{foo: string}`, `{bar: string}`, and `{}` are all valid supertypes of `B`.

Comment: If you want something like this you'll have to add and maintain such information to your classes (e.g., give the class a `superClass` property).  If that works I can make an answer, otherwise I think the answer is just "no, sorry". Good luck!